# When scroll the page horizontally the scrolled part of page does not styling with css color

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have web page which is very dynamic. It has angularJS, bootstrap...
However, the page has horizontal scroll, but there is problem which i cannot handle. When i scroll the page horizontally the rest of the page does not seems to styling with css. You can look at the pictures below: 
[image]
[image]

As you can see in the 2. image the rest of page does not colored when scroll horizontally. This is continue for all page. I am sorry for there is no code because all page is created dynamically. I hope the images help enough. The page include full bootstrap 3. How can i handle this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Please create a plnkr or fiddle to reproduce it.

Comment: Hey Caner, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. A good test case is very important if you want help. I have also found that creating a minimal test case often reveals what the underlying bug is without having to get help. As far as your issue, reading this should help you: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/